# Woocommerce $order->payment_complete(); Internal server error

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, payment-gateway

I'm getting an internal server error calling this $order->payment_complete();
But when I check orders in WC I have a record in procesing and the stock was reduced. My wordpress version is 5.9 and WC 6.1.0

Here is how looks my piece of code.

if(  strlen($response) > 0  ) {

```
                $arr = json_decode( $response, true );
                $body = $arr['body'][0];
                
               
                if ( trim($body['result']) == '1' ) {
                                     
                   file_put_contents('C:/log.txt', 'After payment complete ');
                                          
                   $order->payment_complete();

                   //$order->reduce_order_stock(); Deprecated

                   file_put_contents('C:/log.txt', 'Before payment complete ');
```

Comment: Is this running on a server?

Comment: Yes, it is running

Comment: We would need additional code then. There isn't a lot to go on here.